# Optimization in spark (collect) & transformations of RDD inside an RDD

Tags: scala, optimization, apache-spark

I have the following lines of code in Spark -

```
var y = f.join(varietyFrac).map{case(name,(frac,varietyFrac))=>(name,pow((frac.toDouble*varietyFrac.toDouble),0.01)/0.01)}

var num = y.values.collect()
```

where y has the following data format -

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Double)] = MappedRDD[52]
```

and has 23518 rows. I use the variable `num` for this operation in spark

```
y.map{case(k,v)=>(k,(num.filter(_<=v).length.toDouble/num.length.toDouble))}.
```

For the number of rows collecting the terms seems really slow. It takes ~ 3 minutes to collect. I tried to use y.values as an RDD without the transformation but then I get the following error when I try to retrieve the values -

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations
```

Any comments or ideas on how I can optimize this would be great! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, you can't reference RDDs inside of other transformations. When your data is small enough, collecting the result for one of the RDDs back locally and then using the native collection can work well (as you have also already discovered). Further optimization can be found by using Spark's broadcast facility. Also since you are computing y multiple times, caching y will be able to avoid doing some repeated computation. Further more, since you are repeatedly filtering for values less than some value on nums, sorting (in the driver) and then using the sorted version + binary search may be faster for your use case. Hope that helps :)